# Magento 2.3 checkout page hang up due to knockoutjs or underscore

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, magento2.3, script

After **Magento 2.2.4 upgraded to Magento 2.3.0** checkout page is not working.
 **Checkout page hang up browser** and showing browser warning to **stop it**.
 When clicking on stop it is showing some **jquery warning** in the console  like:

> Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
>   evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection@https://192.168.0.73/pub/static/frontend/MYTHME/CHILD/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2122:1

Or sometimes it is showing warning from other js like `underscore.js`
And it is happening particularly in step 2 of the checkout page.

Comment: do you have an ad-blocker running?

Comment: No, not running any ad-blocker.

Comment: Error: Script terminated by timeout at: ko.observableArray.fn[methodName]@https://192.168.0.73/pub/static/frontend/THEME/MY_THEME/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1690:1